# How can I add a new row to a table filled by an IDataReader?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, datareader

I'm trying to add a new entry to a `DataTable` after I load it with the info contained in an `IDataReader` object, a `DbDataReader` concretely. The loading goes fine and the query to the database is correct I think.

When trying to add a new row I get an `ArgumentException` with the following info:

```
Cannot set column 'ID'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column.
```

This is the code I have right now:

```
// Build the query:
DbCommand cmd = dbCon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name || ' ' || SurName AS FullName FROM Clients ORDER BY FullName;";
// Execute it:
DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Construct the table out of the query result:
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table .Load(reader);
table.Rows.Add(0, "None");
```

In the database (SQLite) `ID` is of type `INTEGER` and both `Name` and `SurName` are `VARCHAR`s. Am I doing something wrong? How could `0` violate the MaxLength limit?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is raised on the line where you add the row manually and not on that where you load the table from the reader?

Comment: I think so, then executing through the Visual Studio debugger that's the line linked to the exception.

Comment: If your ID is a non text column, the MaxLength property should be ignored.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.maxlength.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm... the error I had appears whenever the table is empty, there's no rows returned by the query. When there's something in there, for example 1 row `(1, "Test Test")` I get a different exception in the `Load()` method when the table gets populated: ConstraintException : Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. Maybe it's better to go through the reader manually instead.

Comment: You can always look what causes the `ConstraintException` by using the debugger. Execute `table.Load(reader)` in a QuickWatch Dialog Box. Afterwards execute `table.GetErrors()`. Then you can look into the returned rows at their `RowError` property. Voilà!

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you very much! I didn't know of that and it showed me where the error was exactly. It appears that before you can populate a `DataTable` with info from an `IDataReader` object the columns for it have to be created, it won't load the columns from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally you've solved the issue by using one of my favourite debugger "tricks" to un-mistify strange `DataTable` exceptions. From comments:

> You can always look what causes the ConstraintException by using the
>   debugger. Execute table.Load(reader) in a QuickWatch Dialog Box.
>   Afterwards execute table.GetErrors(). Then you can look into the
>   returned rows at their RowError property. Voilà!

Since i'm using [`DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx) in almost all cases, i've forgotten that [`DataTable.Load(IDataReader)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx) infers the schema based on the result set from the imported `IDataReader`. But of course it needs at least one `DataRow` to do so. That was the reason why it works when the `DataTable` wasn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check the MaxLength property on your ID column in your datatable

```
  size = dataTables(0).Columns(0).MaxLength
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/306971.aspx

Comment: ok that should be a property you can set so set it to like 10 or something you also might need to set the DataColumn.DataType per above comment